# How to get the response from the keyboard input in telegram bot?

Tags: c#, bots, telegram-bot

I want to use custom keyboard to get the selected option.

How to get the selected option ? Is there any example?

my question is answered by "node-telegram-bot-api"

here: [How to get the response of the keyboard selection?](https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api/issues/108)

Is there any solution for c#?

Comment: Which library are you using to access the Telegram Bot API?

Comment: I use telegram.bot

Answer (score 1):

To create a custom keyboard you have to sent a text message and pass a `IReplyMarkup`. The selected option is sent as a message which can be handled in the `OnMessage` event. You can hide the custom keyboard when you set a `ReplyKeyboardHide` as reply markup.

Here is an example:

```
private const string FirstOptionText = "First option";
private const string SecondOptionText = "Second option";

private async void BotClientOnMessage(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Message.Text)
    {
        case FirstOptionText:
            await BotClient.SendTextMessageAsync(e.Message.Chat.Id, "You chose the first option", replyMarkup:new ReplyKeyboardHide());
            break;
        case SecondOptionText:
            await BotClient.SendTextMessageAsync(e.Message.Chat.Id, "You chose the second option", replyMarkup:new ReplyKeyboardHide());
            break;

        default:
            await BotClient.SendTextMessageAsync(e.Message.Chat.Id, "Hi, select an option!",
                replyMarkup: new ReplyKeyboardMarkup(new[]
                {
                    new KeyboardButton(FirstOptionText),
                    new KeyboardButton(SecondOptionText),
                }));
            break;
    }
}
```

Here is a chat with a custom keyboard:
[image]

Here is a chat where I clicked the first button:
[image]

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

When you call [`SendTextMessageAsync`](https://mrroundrobin.github.io/telegram.bot/html/M_Telegram_Bot_TelegramBotClient_SendTextMessageAsync.htm), you pass an `IReplyMarkup` object which specifies a "custom reply keyboard". I don't know much about the Telegram Bot API, but this looks to be the same feature referred to by the GitHub issue you linked.

There appear to be [several implementations listed in the API documentation](https://mrroundrobin.github.io/telegram.bot/html/N_Telegram_Bot_Types_ReplyMarkups.htm). I suspect either `InlineKeyboardMarkup` or `ReplyKeyboardMarkup` is what you're looking for.

Comment: I am looking for ReplyKeyboardMarkup